# ServiceProvider with a singleton asking for primitive types in controller method DI

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, autowired, service-provider

I'm trying to create ServiceProvider for duplicated code in my Laravel application. My solution throws an exception:

```
Illuminate \ Contracts \ Container \ BindingResolutionException:

Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> string $shortName ]] in class App\Domain\Translation\GetTranslation
```

I have a custom abstract controller where I have a simple singleton function:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\WWW;

class CustomController {
(...)
        app()->singleton(
            GetTranslation::class, function() {
            return new GetTranslation(
                TrimSuffixFromUrl::getShortName(),
                LanguageMap::getLanguageIdByCode(\LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale()),
                app()->make(CurrentLanguage::class)
            );
        });
(...)
}
```

This singleton is used in a concrete controller named CreateAccount:

```php
class CreateAccount extends ControllerWWW
{
    public function index(Request $request, DbInstanceFactory $dbInstance, GetTranslation $translation)
    {
        $getTranslation = $translation; // For simplify this example I remove logic
        // (...)
    }
```

I want to create `ServiceProvider`:

```php
<?php 
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Domain\Domains\Prefix\TrimSuffixFromUrl;
use App\Domain\Language\CurrentLanguage;
use App\Domain\Translation\GetTranslation;
use App\Repository\LanguageMap;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

/**
 * Class TranslatioServiceProvider
 * @package App\Providers
 */
class TranslationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        app()->singleton(
            GetTranslation::class, function() {
                return new GetTranslation(
                    TrimSuffixFromUrl::getShortName(),
                    LanguageMap::getLanguageIdByCode(\LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale()),
                    app()->make(CurrentLanguage::class)
                );
            }
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides(): array
    {
        parent::provides();

        return [GetTranslation::class];
    }
}
```

And I add this service to `app.php`:

```php
'providers' => [
    App\Providers\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
]
```

I know the Laravel tries to resolve dependencies for this service but I don't know how to write this code to resolve primitives in a controller.

In other hand, this class - `GetTranslation` - is connected with my views, for example:

```php
<?php
// resources/lang/br/validation.php
declare(strict_types=1);

$translation = app()->make(\App\Domain\Translation\GetTranslation::class);

return [
    'required' => $translation->getTranslationsByKey('tranlation_my_key')
];
```

How to run this service provider in controller and in views - but i don't need run `->singleton()` method in abstract controller. I think the place for this method is in Provider folder, not in controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem this way:

1. Create `TranslationInterface` - even empty.
2. Implement this interface in `GetTranslation::class` like:

```
class GetTranslation implements TranslationInterface {}
```

3. I find all usages of `app()->make(GetTranslation::class);` and replace them with `app()->make(TranslationInterface::class);`